# Object-c run code after a variable's value changed , how to?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 NSItemProviderCompletionHandler urlHandler = ^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
     my_url = url.absoluteString;              
 };


if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.url"]) {
      [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.url" options:nil completionHandler:urlHandler];

}


[self finishSelectingPost:itemProvider data:data];
```

how do I run the last line after my_url  value changed ?  thanks ~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is `my_url` and where is `data`, but supposing they are valid in the context of provided code snapshot, the handler could be as following

```
 __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

 NSItemProviderCompletionHandler urlHandler = ^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      my_url = url.absoluteString;
      [weakSelf finishSelectingPost:itemProvider data:data];
    }
 };
```